# How can I keep text chat panel open in Google Meet

Tags: google-meet

I am using [Google Meet](https://meet.google.com/). I am doing presentation, and want the class to respond in text chat. This works well, except that after a while the program notices that I am reading the chat, and closes it. It sometimes also scrolls to the top.

Is there a way to pin the text chat to stay open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A put in a bug request. And less than a week later they changed it to not auto-close.

So now the answer is do nothing (It just works).